# Regrads to listbox in web from using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have list box on   in web application app inasp.net c#, the list box contains several items, the items are populated from a database.
My problem is, I want the list box to deselect all other options when top  particular one is selected, My list box name is list_Store and list box items are  given below in order

```
ALL 
kk Stores
calicut stores
home store
reliance
```

So Items kk Stores,  home store,reliance can all be selected together, but when 'ALL' is selected I want all others to be deselect

pls help me get out of tthis problem 
thank you

Comment: I am just enter into asp.net , I didn't try anything

Comment: you won't do well on StackOverflow then.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a jquery, you can do this by

writing a javascript change event handler and check if the All is selected, deselect all options and select All option by code again.

```
var selectedValue = $('#myselect option:selected').val();
var table = selectedValue.split(',');
for(i = 0 ; i < table.length; i++) {
    if (table[i] == 'All')
    {
       $('#mySelect').find("option").attr("selected", false);
       $("#mySelect option[value='All']").attr("selected", true");
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw JS version. Assumes 'ALL' is the first option on the list (as given in question)

```
function updateSel() {
    var list = document.getElementById("<%= Listbox1.ClientID %>");
    if (list.options[0].selected) {
        for (var i = 1; i < list.options.length; i++) {
            list.options[i].selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be called in the 'onChange' property of the ListBox.

Comment: If this code meets your needs, consider accepting it as an answer.